# What is advantage of using Dryad instead of Spark?

Tags: bigdata

I found that Apache-Spark very powerful in Big-Data processing. but I want to know about Dryad (Microsoft) benefits. Is there any advantage for this framework than Spark?

Why we must use Dryad instead of Spark?

Comment: Just a comment - there's another good tool comparable with Spark which is called "Apache Flink". In some cases it's better, so you might want to check it out as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dryad is an academic project, whereas Spark is widely deployed in production, and now has a company behind it for support. Just focus on Spark.

Answer (score 2):

Spark is based on Dryad research work